# How to concatenate three columns into one and obtain count of unique entries among them using Cypher neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I can query using Cypher in Neo4j from the [Panama](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj7orCN7bXTAhWPalAKHdsSB2oQFggyMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Foffshoreleaks.icij.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNHfCoVJUQDbNOd9oLvsOAnh8nNjiw&sig2=wOmFx4c0izobuj-kyNjwsA) database the countries of three types of identity holders (I define that term) namely Entities (companies), officers (shareholders) and Intermediaries (middle companies) as three attributes/columns. Each column has single or double entries separated by colon (eg: British Virgin Islands;Russia). We want to concatenate the countries in these columns into a unique set of countries and hence obtain the count of the number of countries as new attribute.

For this, I tried the following code from my understanding of Cypher:

```
MATCH (BEZ2:Officer)-[:SHAREHOLDER_OF]->(BEZ1:Entity),(BEZ3:Intermediary)-[:INTERMEDIARY_OF]->(BEZ1:Entity)
WHERE BEZ1.address CONTAINS "Belize" AND 
  NOT ((BEZ1.countries="Belize" AND  BEZ2.countries="Belize" AND BEZ3.countries="Belize") OR
    (BEZ1.status IN ["Inactivated", "Dissolved shelf company", "Dissolved", "Discontinued", "Struck / Defunct / Deregistered", "Dead"]))
SET BEZ4.countries= (BEZ1.countries+","+BEZ2.countries+","+BEZ3.countries) 
RETURN BEZ3.countries AS IntermediaryCountries, BEZ3.name AS 
  Intermediaryname, BEZ2.countries AS OfficerCountries , BEZ2.name AS 
  Officername, BEZ1.countries as EntityCountries, BEZ1.name AS Companyname, 
  BEZ1.address AS CompanyAddress,DISTINCT count(BEZ4.countries) AS NoofConnections
```

The relevant part is the SET statement in the 7th line and the DISTINCT count in the last line. The code shows error which makes no sense to me: Invalid input 'u': expected 'n/N'. I guess it means to use COLLECT probably but we tried that as well and it shows the error vice-versa'd between 'u' and 'n'. Please help us obtain the output that we want, it makes our job hell lot easy. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Considering I didn't define variable as suggested by @Cybersam, I tried the command CREATE as following but it shows the error "Invalid input 'R':" for the command RETURN. This is unfathomable for me. Help really needed, thank you.

CODE 2:

```
MATCH (BEZ2:Officer)-[:SHAREHOLDER_OF]->(BEZ1:Entity),(BEZ3:Intermediary)-
[:INTERMEDIARY_OF]->(BEZ1:Entity)
WHERE BEZ1.address CONTAINS "Belize" AND 
NOT ((BEZ1.countries="Belize" AND  BEZ2.countries="Belize" AND 
BEZ3.countries="Belize") OR
(BEZ1.status IN ["Inactivated", "Dissolved shelf company", "Dissolved", 
"Discontinued", "Struck / Defunct / Deregistered", "Dead"]))
CREATE (p:Connections{countries: 
split((BEZ1.countries+";"+BEZ2.countries+";"+BEZ3.countries),";")
RETURN BEZ3.countries AS IntermediaryCountries, BEZ3.name AS 
Intermediaryname, BEZ2.countries AS OfficerCountries , BEZ2.name AS 
Officername, BEZ1.countries as EntityCountries, BEZ1.name AS Companyname, 
BEZ1.address AS CompanyAddress,  AS TOTAL, collect (DISTINCT 
COUNT(p.countries)) AS NumberofConnections
```

Lines 8 and 9 are the ones new and to be in examination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First Query

You never defined the identifier `BEZ4`, so you cannot set a property on it.

#### Second Query (*which should have been posted in a separate question*):

You have several typos and a syntax error.

This query should not get an error (but you will have to determine if it does what you want):

```
MATCH (BEZ2:Officer)-[:SHAREHOLDER_OF]->(BEZ1:Entity),(BEZ3:Intermediary)- [:INTERMEDIARY_OF]->(BEZ1:Entity)
WHERE BEZ1.address CONTAINS "Belize" AND  NOT ((BEZ1.countries="Belize" AND  BEZ2.countries="Belize" AND  BEZ3.countries="Belize") OR (BEZ1.status IN ["Inactivated", "Dissolved shelf company", "Dissolved",  "Discontinued", "Struck / Defunct / Deregistered", "Dead"]))
CREATE (p:Connections {countries: split((BEZ1.countries+";"+BEZ2.countries+";"+BEZ3.countries), ";")})
RETURN BEZ3.countries AS IntermediaryCountries,
  BEZ3.name AS  Intermediaryname,
  BEZ2.countries AS OfficerCountries ,
  BEZ2.name AS  Officername,
  BEZ1.countries as EntityCountries,
  BEZ1.name AS Companyname,
  BEZ1.address AS CompanyAddress,
  SIZE(p.countries) AS NumberofConnections;
```

Problems with the original:

- The `CREATE` clause was missing a closing `}` and also a closing `)`.
- The `RETURN` clause had a dangling `AS TOTAL` term.
- `collect (DISTINCT COUNT(p.countries))` was attempting to perform nested aggregation, which is not supported. In any case, even if it had worked, it probably would not have returned what you wanted. I suspect that you actually wanted the size of the `p.countries` collection, so that is what I used in my query.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it. After trying other options, for me the command in EDIT seems appropriate but still gives error Invalid input 'R': near RETURN. Please help, thank you!

Comment: See my updated answer. *You should have really created a new question for the new issue.*

Comment: Lol, sorry for the silly mistakes. I will be more prudent. Thank you, the 'size' command which I didn't figure out half solves my problem. But as I mention in my question, my goal is to obtain unique/distinct size and the command Distinct doesn't work in front of SIZE or after CREATE. Do you think it's not possible to unduplicate string values in p.countries?

Comment: Hello @Cybersam, gentle reminder to please help me out finding unique number of countries in size. Distinct SIZE(p.countries) AS pops an error that AS should be AND instead